# How do I kill running map tasks on Amazon EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dictionary, hadoop, amazon-emr

I have a job running using Hadoop 0.20 on 32 spot instances.  It has been running for 9 hours with no errors.  It has processed 3800 tasks during that time, but I have noticed that just two tasks appear to be stuck and have been running alone for a couple of hours (apparently responding because they don't time out).  The tasks don't typically take more than 15 minutes.  I don't want to lose all the work that's already been done, because it costs me a lot of money.  I would really just like to kill those two tasks and have Hadoop either reassign them or just count them as failed.  Until they stop, I cannot get the reduce results from the other 3798 maps!

But I can't figure out how to do that.  I have considered trying to figure out which instances are running the tasks and then terminate those instances, but

1. I don't know how to figure out which instances are the culprits
2. I am afraid it will have unintended effects.

How do I just kill individual map tasks?

Comment: Though I am still interested in answers to this for future reference, I discovered that tasks will commit suicide after 3 hours.  So they are now dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, on a Hadoop cluster you can kill a particular task by issuing:

```
hadoop job -kill-task [attempt_id]
```

This will kill the given map task and re-submits it on an different
node with a new id.

To get the `attemp_id` navigate on the `Jobtracker`'s `web UI` to the map task
in question, click on it and note it's id (e.g: attempt_201210111830_0012_m_000000_0)

Comment: This is great when I am running on a local Hadoop cluster and thanks for that.  How can I make this work on EMR though?  Is there an elastic-mapreduce command line option for this?  I couldn't find one.

Comment: I did see that I can ssh into the master node: `./elastic-mapreduce —ssh —jobflow JobFlowID`.  Can I then execute the above command?

Comment: Ssh to the master node ( docs: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html ) and issue bin/hadoop job to see what options you have

Answer (score 1):

ssh to the master node as mentioned by Lorand, and execute:

```
bin/hadoop job -list
bin/hadoop job –kill <JobID>
```